# How do I use sitemap.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I installed the node module [sitemap.js](https://github.com/ekalinin/sitemap.js) to generate a sitemap.xml for my website. However, I am fairly new to node/express/sails so I don't quite understand the instructions on the git page. Under the section "Usage" where is that code supposed to go? How do I execute the module so that the xml will be generated?

Comment: Is your site running on NodeJS? If not, I don't think this is what you're looking for. It's not going to crawl your site and spit out an XML file, it just accepts URLs and keeps an XML Sitemap in memory while the Node proccess is running that can be exposed by an endpoint.

Comment: @AlexHill Yes, it's running on node. sails.js, to be specific. If it does what you say it does then it's indeed not what I am looking for but in that case, the description is kind of confusing, at least to me. "sitemap.js is a high-level sitemap-generating framework that makes creating sitemap XML files easy." Reading that description, I'd have thought crawling the site and collecting the urls is exactly what it does.

Comment: It does generate a sitemap, just not as a static file. It sounds like you want something like [Screaming Frog](http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/)

Comment: @AlexHill That looks like a very helpful tool but I am just looking for a simple plugin (aka node module) that automatically generates a sitemap.xml file for my site. I used http://www.web-site-map.com/index.php to generate the file for now but I'd prefer an automated, dynamic plugin that keeps track of added and removed pages and generates the xml file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly this is for my tables, but this is how I've created a static (I update it using `cron` once per week) `sitemap.xml` using `sitemap`.

```
'use strict';

var sm = require('sitemap')
var fs = require('fs');

var photoModel = require('../../models/photo');
var db  = require('../../models/db');

var config = require('../../config');

var hostname = config.siteUrl

var queryParams = {
    active: 1,
    sortOrder: 'desc',
    sortBy: 'relevance',
}

var photoQuery = db.rawSQL([
    'SELECT img_id, tags',
    'FROM images',
    'WHERE active = 1'
]);

function createSiteMap(myURLs) {
    var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({
        hostname: hostname,
        cacheTime: 600000,  //600 sec (10 min) cache purge period 
        urls: myURLs
        });
    fs.writeFileSync("public/sitemap.xml", sitemap.toString());    
    process.exit();
}

function uniq(a) {
    var seen = {};
    return a.filter(function(item) {
        return seen.hasOwnProperty(item) ? false : (seen[item] = true);
    });
}

function getPhotos() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var siteMapArray = new Array()
        var tags = new Array()
        siteMapArray.push ({ url: '/' , changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8, lastmodrealtime: true, lastmodfile: 'views/home.hbs' },)
        db.sequelize.query(photoQuery, {
            replacements: queryParams
        }).spread(function(makeSiteMap) {
            makeSiteMap.forEach(function(obj) {
                var siteLink = { url: 'photo/' + obj.img_id, changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.6, lastmodrealtime: true }
                siteMapArray.push(siteLink);
                obj.tags = obj.tags.split(',').map(function(e) {
                    return e.trim().split(' ').join('+');
                });
                for (var tag in obj.tags) {
                    tags.push(obj.tags[tag])
                }
            });

            resolve (siteMapArray);

            var uniqueTags = uniq(tags);
            for (var tag in uniqueTags) {
                var siteLink = { url: '/search/' + uniqueTags[tag], changefreq: 'weekly', priority: 0.8, lastmodrealtime: true }
                siteMapArray.push (siteLink);
            }

            createSiteMap(siteMapArray);

        });
    });
};

getPhotos();
```